# How to configure JUnit rules to apply to specific test

Tags: java, junit

Is it possible to have a Junit rule only apply to specific tests? If so, how do I do that?

The code below exemplifies what I want to do: each time I have @Rule, I want the method below that to have the specific rule that has been annotated to run with it. I only want that rule to run with the corresponding test. I don't want anything other tests to be affected by the rule.

In this case, when I run these tests, I see that one of the tests the EmptyFileCheck, gives a File DNE does not exist, but I have used a separate annotation for that function, so I had thought that it would run with a different context, supplying the Empty, but instead DNE is till being used.

```
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.setIn;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.channels.Pipe;

import static org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.allOf;

import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.core.AllOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import org.hamcrest.text.StringContains;
import org.hamcrest.text.StringEndsWith;
import org.hamcrest.text.StringStartsWith;
import org.jmock.Expectations;
import org.jmock.Mockery;
import org.jmock.lib.legacy.ClassImposteriser;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.TextFromStandardInputStream;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

public class UnitTests {
    private Mockery context = new Mockery() {{
        setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    }};
    private main mn;
    private InputStream oldIn;
    private PrintStream oldOut;
    private InputStream mockIn;
    private InputStreamReader mockinputStream;
    private PrintStream mockOut;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private Expectations exp;


    @Before
    public void setMinimalMockingExpectations() throws IOException {
        exp = new Expectations() {{ }};
        mn = context.mock(main.class);
        mockinputStream = context.mock(InputStreamReader.class);
        oldIn = System.in;
        oldOut = System.out;
        mockIn = context.mock(InputStream.class);
        mockOut = context.mock(PrintStream.class);
        System.setOut(mockOut);
    }

    public void configureExpectations(boolean fileOrInput, boolean verbosity) { 
        exp.one(mockOut).println("Do you want to process standard (I)nput, or a (F)ile? I/F");
        if (fileOrInput) { //it's a file
            exp.one(mockOut).println("Enter filename: ");
        } else { //it's not

        }
    }

    @After
    public void reset() {
        System.setOut(oldOut);
    }

    @Rule
    public final TextFromStandardInputStream FileNotFoundException 
        = new TextFromStandardInputStream("F\nDNE\n");
    @Test(expected=FileNotFoundException.class)
    public void EnsureFileCheckExists() throws IOException {
        final String fileName = "DNE";
        configureExpectations(true, false);
        exp.one(mn).checkFile(fileName); 
        context.checking(exp); 
        mn.main(null);
    }

    @Rule
    public final TextFromStandardInputStream FileReadAccessDenied
        = new TextFromStandardInputStream("F\nUnderPriviledged\n");:w

    @Test(expected=FileNotFoundException.class)
    public void FileReadAccessDenied() throws java.io.FileNotFoundException {
        final String fileName = "UnderPriviledged";
        configureExpectations(true, false);
        //exp.oneOf(mn).checkFile(with());  TODO: fix ME!
        context.checking(exp);
        mn.main(null);
    }

    @Rule
    public final TextFromStandardInputStream EmptyFileCheck 
        = new TextFromStandardInputStream("F\nEmpty\n");
    @Test
    public void EmptyFileCheck() throws java.io.FileNotFoundException {
        final String fileName = "Empty";
        configureExpectations(true, false);
        exp.one(mn).checkFile(fileName);
        context.checking(exp);
        mn.main(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a setter in your Rule which is the first thing that gets called in the rule. Something like this, from [ExpectedException](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html):

```
// These tests all pass.
public static class HasExpectedException {
     @Rule
     public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();

     @Test
     public void throwsNothing() {
         // no exception expected, none thrown: passes.
     }

     @Test
     public void throwsNullPointerException() {
         thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
         throw new NullPointerException();
     }

     @Test
     public void throwsNullPointerExceptionWithMessage() {
         thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
         thrown.expectMessage("happened?");
         thrown.expectMessage(startsWith("What"));
         throw new NullPointerException("What happened?");
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you think that I could use a string argument and reflection to make sure that the function matches before running it?

Answer (score 3):

Any reason not to just take the code out of the @rule annotation and move it to the start of the test body?

Comment: That's not good practice because then you have replicated code at the beginning of every test. Yes, you could even put that much in a function it out, but it works best as a third party utility that can be downloaded, and therefore should be modified. If that were to happen, then code reusability is maximized. Although I do acknowledge that what you have suggested will definitely solve my problem.

Comment: Surely code replicated inside a test body is the same as code replicated just before a test body? Both end up with the things that are unique to a test step written per-step, and things that are common to all test steps off in separate functions, objects or packages. Both solutions are equally reusable, downloadable, etc.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have permission to modify the other's code. Plus, I already wrote my tests. I would have done what you said, but I can't...

That said, now that I think about it, I see you're point, and had I done it your way, I'd have stuck all my tests in one class. But I've already done the work, and it was for a class project that I don't think deserves my attention. So yeah, I should have refactored it, but I'm lazy, it's already done.